# Using multiple regression model from training set to predict test data in R

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, prediction

I am an undergrad student and I'm super new to R! I have a data set that I have split into a training and test set. I obtained a multiple regression model from my training set, and now I want to use it to predict my test data. My dependent variable is Plant Species Richness (PSR), and my original data set had 4 independent variables (Area, AdjacentWetlands, Roads, and Forest) but my model is only using Area and Forest: `LM<-lm(PSR~Area+Forest, data=Wetlands)`. How do I use this model to predict PSR in my test set? And then how do I assess whether it is a good prediction or not?

Comment: Split-sample validation takes an amazingly large sample size to work in the sense of providing almost the same answer if you were to repeat the single random split and re-do all model building and all validation calculations.  What is your total sample size?

Comment: If you're interested in learning about machine learning and R, I'd highly recommend checking out [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf), which is a great book that is freely available as a pdf. It has many examples in R, including cross validation (Chapter 5)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, get your model:

`LM <- lm(PSR ~ Area+Forests, data = Wetlands)`

Make sure all data values are correct.

The function `predict()` does the calculation:

`pred <- pred(your_model, your_data_test)`

Your issue seems that `your_data_test` have more variables than your model, right?

So you can slice `your_data_test` and put into a `new_data_test` by using

`new_data_test <- data.frame(your_data_test$variable1,your_data_test$variable2)`

and then

`pred <- pred(yourmodel, new_data_test)`

I suppose should be work for you.

Comment: I tried your solution on a similar dataset, but this gives a warning: " 'newdata' had 15600 rows but variables found have 1164007 rows  " 

Also the created predict vector is not of 15600 length as it should be, but of 1164007 length.

Comment: Please check your data and try to catch any inconsistency in the values.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to create new_data_set. Instead, simply use your_data_test to get pred since your_model (LM) restricts to its entries (2 variables as mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use print(summary(LM)) to access the accuracy of your model. You'll also get to know of other vitals like r^2 value, p-value of each predictor which helps you decide on a model.

Comment: this is true and generally helpful, but the OP asks _"How do I use this model to predict PSR in my test set? And then how do I assess whether it is a good prediction or not?"_